# Manipulating Values Python Dictionary (JSON Object)

Tags: python, json, variables, dictionary, python-requests

I'm using requests in python for dealing with sending data (Post + JSON)

Here is my problem:

```
payload = {"credentials": {"deviceid": "XXX","pin": "XXX"},"data": [{"id": "","name": "","type": "","data": [{"value": "","date": ""}]}]}
```

Then I want to fill the blank values ("" not XXX) by variables in Python

```
payload["id"] = payload_id
payload["name"] = payload_name
payload["type"] = payload_type
payload["value"] = payload_value
payload["date"] = payload_datetime
```

If I print now

```
payload["id"]
```

everything works.

But if I print the whole

```
print payload
```

Then the value is not changed. But the value has been added. Than I have two of each. One empty and one with the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go down to the correct level i.e. `payload["data"][0]["id"]` instead of `payload["id"]`

Thus, it should be :

```
payload["data"][0]["id"] = payload_id
payload["data"][0]["name"] = payload_name
payload["data"][0]["type"] = payload_type
payload["data"][0]["data"][0]["value"] = payload_value
payload["data"][0]["data"][0]["date"] = payload_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***id*** key is part of a dictionary that is a member of a list that contains another dictionary that you must access with the ***data*** key.

`payload["data"][0]["id"]`

Comment: I'm writing as a reviewer because your answer has been flagged for its quality. Would you please add commentary that explains your answer and indicates why it is a correct response.

Comment: Hope it's ok now.

Comment: Much better! --